# it should be clickable only when mouse is hovered over text or icon

Tags: css

This the text `Test Button` which is clickable to do some activity but since by default the width is 100% so on hovering mouse over blank space after the text is also clickable. We can reduce the width but the problem is there is border-bottom which is required to have 100% width
[image]

Comment: put the border on the parent then.

Comment: Try to post your markup :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try wrapping the text in a span and add the onclick to that - like

```css
button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  background: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green; 
  text-align: left;
}

button span {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button svg { 
  display: inline;
  width:  9px;
  height: 9px;
  margin-right: 9px
}
```

```html
<button>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path stroke="currentcolor" stroke-width="2" fill="none" d="M1 1h14v14H1z M3 8h10M8 3v10"/></svg>
  <span onclick="alert('add onclick to span')">TEST BUTTON</span> 
</button>
```